# How to properly Capture Audio with DirectShow

Tags: c++, directx, directshow

Basiclly I just want to capture audio and save it to a file on disk. I came to the conlusion using the AVI format would be best and least annoying. After wading through the DirectShow API, this is what I came up with.

```
//I find the mic in previous code
hr = pMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pSrc);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&pGraph);
//Initialize the Capture Graph Builder
hr = pBuild->SetFiltergraph(pGraph);

IBaseFilter *pMux;
//IFileSinkFilter *pSink;
hr = pBuild->SetOutputFileName(
    &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
    L"C:\\Example.avi", // File name.
    &pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
    NULL);              // (Optional) Receives a pointer to the file sink.


hr = pBuild->RenderStream(
    &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
    &MEDIATYPE_Audio,      // Media type.
    pSrc,                  // Capture filter.
    NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
    pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.
```

Now, I figured this would be enough to do what I wanted but no file is created on disk and RenderStream gives me E_INVALDARGS. If I change the function call to:

```
hr = pBuild->RenderStream(
    NULL, // Pin category.
NULL,      // Media type.
    pSrc,                  // Capture filter.
    NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
    pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.
```

I get the VFW_E_NOT_IN_GRAPH error instead.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd be outmost grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VFW_E_NOT_IN_GRAPH` means that you need to add your `pSrc` filter you created to the filter graph using `IGraphBuilder::AddFilter` call.

To save audio-only stream into file, you might want to prefer .WAV format instead, Windows SDK comes with `WavDest` project/sample which can accept audio from audio filter and output a .WAV file stream compatible with `File Writer Filter` to save into file.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. That removed the error. By adding hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pSrc, L"AudioCap"); Though, one thing I dont understand, how do i get to to start capturing to a file and saving it? I see no file being produced. Am i supposed to add controls? Oh and the reason i picked AVI is that I dont want to have to build filters and register them, like with WavDest. Im planning on compressing later on.

Comment: Once you have your pipeline built, you query IMediaControl interface from filter graph, and call `IMediaControl::Run()` to start things rolling. Then, `IMediaControl::Stop()` will complete recording and close the file.

Comment: Yeah I just solved it. DirectShow is just awesome for audio/video capture. I started out testing waveInOpen and those old APIs but DirectShow is a lot less complicated. Thanks a lot for your help :)